# The Run button on PopSQL not working [greyed out]

Tags: popsql

The run button in PopSQL greyed out a while ago after I restarted my laptop. No matter how I tried I couldn't click on it. I re-checked, double-checked my queries but it still didn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, check the following -

1. Your query - Check for semantic errors.
2. Your database connection - There may be some fault in the connection itself. Try connecting again with the database. Check if just above the tab where the connection is specified if you can see your database name like this -

[image]

If you have just installed MySQL in your laptop (or anyways, now you don't have any other option) -

1. Open run from Start Menu or press windows key + R.
2. Search for 'services.msc'.

[image]

3. In the search window, search for MySQL80. Double click on it to open.
   [image]
4. You will notice that the service is either disabled (in startup type) or stopped in the service status.
5. Select Automatic or Automatic (Delayed start) in the select box of Startup type and click on apply. So that whenever your machine starts the MySQL service will start automatically in the background.

[image]

6. After that click on the Start button to start the MySQL service on your machine. It will take a few seconds to start.
7. Then click on apply and hit Ok. Then close the services window also.
8. Now try opening PopSQL you'll see that database connection has been corrected.

ENJOY!!!